# React-Admin filters that relate to the current results

Tags: react-admin

We're really enjoying using the capabilities offered by React-Admin.

We're using `<ReferenceArrayInput>` to allow filtering of a `<List>` by `Country`.  The drop-down contains all countries in the database.

But, we'd like it to just contain the countries that relate to the current set of filtered records.

So, in the context of the React-Admin demo, if we've filtered for `Returned`, then the `Customer` drop-down would only contain customers who have returned items (see below). This would make a real-difference in finding the records of interest.

Our current plan is to (somehow) handle this in our `<DataProvider>`.  But, is there are more ReactAdmin friendly way of doing this?

[image: Customer drop-down]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to build dependent filters, which is not a native feature of react-admin - and a complex beast to tame.

First, doing so in the dataProvider will not work, because you'll only have the data of the first page of results. A record in a following page may have another value for your array input.

You could implement that logic in a custom Input component instead. This component can wrap the original `<ReferenceArrayInput>` and read the current  ListContext to get the current data and filter value (https://marmelab.com/react-admin/useListContext.html), then alter the array of possible values using the filter prop (https://marmelab.com/react-admin/ReferenceArrayInput.html#filter).

Comment: Sure, thanks for that François - I was just doing "due diligence" before we (eventually) write our own implementation.